# How to update my Users/Products association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I'm trying to create an app to share or give products. So I have two models : User and Product.
A user can have many products, as an owner or as a borrower. A product has only one owner and only one borrower.

First I did something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16537295/how-must-i-structure-my-models-to-connect-owners-borrowers-and-products) :

```rb
> rails generate model User name:string
class User
  has_many :owned_products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :borrowed_products, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
end

> rails generate model Product name:string owner_id:integer borrower_id:integer
class Product
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "borrower_id"
end
```

I added in my Product controller a security filter that enable the update method only for product's owner. But when I want to change the product's borrower, I have some kind of a problem, because the borrower is never the owner, so the product can not be updated.

So now I'm wondering if I should not take the foreign_key out of my products model, in order to dissociate the update action of a user on his own product, and the update action of a user to borrow a product that don't belongs to him...

```rb
> rails generate model User name:string
class User
  has_many :properties
  has_many :loans
  has_many :owned_products, through: :properties
  has_many :borrowed_products, through: :loans
end

> rails generate model Property owner_id:integer owned_product_id:integer
class Property
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :owned_product, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "product_id"
end

> rails generate model Loan borrower_id:integer borrowed_product_id:integer
class Loan
  belongs_to :borrower, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :borrowed_product, class_name: "Product", foreign_key: "product_id"
end

> rails generate model Product name:string
class Product
  has_one :property
  has_one :loan
  has_one :owner, through: :property
  has_one :borrower, through: :loan
end
```

What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Since borrowed products and owned products are the same type of object with the same list of attributes, but differ only in behavior, I would use single table inheritance for `Product`.

Migrations:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      # ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.integer :ownerable_id
      t.string :ownerable_type
      # ...

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :as => :ownerable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true
end

class OwnedProduct < Product
end

class BorrowedProduct < Product
end
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can just define the appropriate behavior in each model without asking it if it's "owned" or "borrowed." Just [tell](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) your models what to do and leave the decisions up to each object to do the right thing.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it will complicate things a lot. The products can be owned and borrowed simultaneously, they're not at all different.

Comment: I don't understand how this is complicated. `User` either owns an object, or it is borrowing an object (because it doesn't own it). And since they're not at all different, this is also reflected in the fact that `Product`, `BorrowedProduct` and `OwnedProduct` all come from the same database table. The only difference is the type of product that rails automatically handles instantiating for you. I also argue that this is significantly simpler, by an order of magnitude, than your other approach of implementing the `Property` and `Loan` models.